# GCP Composer Airflow tasks stuck or frozen

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am setting up some ETL pipelines on Googles Composer Airflow, deployed on a 3 node GKE. The minimum for Airflow Compose from GCP!

Version : 1.10.1-composer

GCP Image version: composer-1.6.0-airflow-1.10.1

I would normally log into airflow machine and try to debug via Ipython but this is difficult to do on GKE setup. I cant seem to ssh into the proper place to run interactive tests to debug.

Python Operator: Using standard GSheetHook

```
def pull_sheet(execution_date=None):
    hook = GSheetHook()
    sheet_data = hook.get_values_df('SHEET_ID_XXXXX',
                                    'EXAMPLEXXXXX!A1:J4305', shape_column=None)
    return print(sheet_data)
```

STALE State in Airflow Logs. The Task has been left for a day (24 hours) with no Timeout Error or any error at all, never marked for retry. The snippet below and screenshot of scheduler logs is the only information i have about the running tasks. From the scheduler logs and it looks like the task keeps running without acknowledging any state changes... [Airflow Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8dJV.png)

```
[2019-10-21 13:15:07,431] {models.py:1361} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: gsheet_test.pull_gsheet 2019-10-20T02:00:00+00:00 [queued]>
[2019-10-21 13:15:07,441] {models.py:1361} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: gsheet_test.pull_gsheet 2019-10-20T02:00:00+00:00 [queued]>
[2019-10-21 13:15:07,442] {models.py:1573} INFO -
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Starting attempt 1 of 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[2019-10-21 13:15:07,490] {models.py:1595} INFO - Executing <Task(PythonOperator): pull_gsheet> on 2019-10-20T02:00:00+00:00
[2019-10-21 13:15:07,491] {base_task_runner.py:118} INFO - Running: ['bash', '-c', 'airflow run gsheet_test pull_gsheet 2019-10-20T02:00:00+00:00 --job_id 70970 --raw -sd DAGS_FOLDER/gsheet_test.py --cfg_path /tmp/tmp3xukhrnx']
```

Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem. What I did was, make `retries= 1 or 2` in DAG parameters, and provided
timeout for the task.

```
execution_timeout=timedelta(hours=1)
```

after 1 hour, if the task still in running state, it will be marked as failed and it will be up for retry.